# React Render Method Clobbering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have recently run into an interesting situation when it comes to the React render method. I have a simple custom `Select` component that works like the HTML `<select>` element. It opens a dropdown list of options, and when an option is selected it:

a) Sets the dropdown's `isVisible` state to `false`.

b) Triggers an `onChange` event.

The trouble I have been experiencing is getting the dropdown to close *immediately* after selecting an option. Closing the dropdown should be performed asynchronously, and not wait for `onChange` to complete. I thought this shouldn't be a problem since we can invoke the `onChange` method in the `setState` callback.

```
handleOnClick(value) {
    this.setState({
      isVisible: false
    }, () => {
      this.props.onChange(value);
    });
  }
```

This did not work as expected. After clicking an option, my dropdown would remain open until my expensive `onChange` operation was finished. My current theory is that `onChange` is causing multiple state changes, which in turn is clobbering the `render` method in my `Select` component. To test this theory I wrapped `this.props.onChange(value);` in a `setTimeout`. Even with a time of `0`, the issue seems to have been resolved. Unfortunately this feels hacky. I would love to better understand what is happening, and what a more elegant solution might be.

Comment: Is `onChange` expensive because it's doing IO or is it cpu intensive? My understanding is that the setState callback guarantees you will have access to the updated state in your component, but does not guarantee to wait for the next render. So depending on what your onChange does, it could still block rendering.

Comment: CPU intensive. And yes that seems to fit with what I am experiencing

Comment: In that case your `setTimeout` hack might be the simplest answer for getting the render to happen before the `onChange` handler. That said, once the `onChange` handler does start your app will probably be unresponsive until it completes. You might want to consider running it in a WebWorker.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like this? https://jsfiddle.net/69z2wepo/296216/

```
    class Select extends React.Component {
    constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        isVisible: false,
      element: "Canada",
    }
  }

  onClickHandler(event){
    this.setState({isVisible: false, element: event.currentTarget.dataset.id});
  }

  onResetElement() {
    this.setState({isVisible: true, element: null });
  }

  render() {
    return (
    <div>
     {this.state.isVisible && 
      <ul className="select">
        <li data-id="Brazil" onClick={::this.onClickHandler}>Brazil</li>
        <li data-id="Canada" onClick={::this.onClickHandler}>Canada</li>
        <li data-id="England" onClick={::this.onClickHandler}>England</li>
      </ul>
      }
      {!this.state.isVisible && <div onClick={::this.onResetElement} className="selected">{this.state.element}</div>}
    </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <Select  />,
  document.getElementById('container')
);
```